# Get table rowIndex of a HTML table without traversing - Only Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have a table that automatically adds new rows, once u go to the last cell and tab over.

I click on one of the cells - I want to know the rowIndex of the clicked cell (row)

I havent been able to uniquely identify the cell using any attribute eg classname etc, ID is randomly generated. Name , TagName everything is generic - Same for all rows.

How do I get the rowIndex just using a cell's info

No jquery sols pls - not allowed in my framework

Comment: "No jquery sols pls - not allowed in my framework", why the jQuery tag then? **Edit**: Removed tag.

Comment: I want jquery people to see it - but It should benefit the JS only ppl

Comment: That's not the point of tags on Stackoverflow. It has to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can grab this info from the parent node `tr` as `rowIndex`:

```
td.parentNode.rowIndex
```

Here `td` is `HTMLTableCellElement` element.

`td` has a reference to its parent row element `parentNode` (tr), which in its own turn has a property `rowIndex`. Similarly `td` itself has a property `cellIndex`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/prFSd/1/

Answer (score 1):

dfsq provides a good answer, but it uses jquery which you said you could not use. You could put this in each row
`onclick="myFunction(this)"`
then define the function

```
function myFunction(x)
{
alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: I used jQuery for demo, to bind click event. You code is not correct HTMLTableCellElement doesn't have `rowIndex` property.

Comment: That's why I said put the onclick handler in the row.

Comment: yes, it's a working solution but not very nice because you end up with loads of onclick handlers. Much more efficient if you can use jquery's on handler attached to the table.

Comment: Not necessary, you can always use plain JS for event delegation. See my updated demo where I did it witout jQuery.

Comment: yep, that's much better than littering the markup with onclick's, nice one.

Comment: Yes. In fact this is how jQuery does event delegation. It benefits from the fact that event bubbles up the DOM tree.